# What is the best way to work with a large JSON splitted between two (or more) buffer chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, buffer

Imagine a situation where you have a large JSON that basically looks like this:

```
{"name": "...", /*...*/, "data": "..."}
```

That JSON is very large actually. Also, that JSON is passed to me in node.js buffer chunks. And because the JSON is large there are two chunks, the first one contains `name` and the second one contains `data`.

The chunks can look like this:

```
{"name": "...", /*...*/, "da //chunk1
ta": "..."} //chunk2
```

I need to modify `data` based on `name`. What is the best practice to do that?

The problem I am stuck with is that I cannot `JSON.parse` this data because of the obvious reasons (including memory consumption). So how do I handle this scenario without `JSON.parse`? Do I have to write my own parser to detect where `data` starts and ends?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566865/parse-streaming-json?

Comment: clearly not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are fairly limited:

1. [Concatenating the buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength), parsing the JSON, and then working with the resulting object tree (memory impact and all).
2. Using (or building) a streaming JSON parser. For instance, [Oboe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js) (no affiliation) is described as:

   > Oboe.js is an open source Javascript library for loading JSON using streaming, combining the convenience of DOM with the speed and fluidity of SAX.
   >
   > It can parse any JSON as a stream, is small enough to be a micro-library, doesn't have dependencies, and doesn't care which other libraries you need it to speak to.
   >
   > We can load trees larger than the available memory. Or we can instantiate classical OOP models from JSON, or completely transform your JSON while it is being read.

   I found that using a search for "node streaming json parser"; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566865/parse-streaming-json) was the second hit, and has an answer referring to Oboe.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, Oboe.js doesn't reduce memory consumption if compared to the first approach you mentioned. It is a great tool for incremental handling of streaming JSON, though!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev - Ah, well, was worth a try. :-)